# How can I do visible for my material-bottom-tabs?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

### How can I make my material bottom tab navigation visible? I have the code and according to the duration I have to put the function, but every time I add this code to my code, Expo gives me error  :

```
 return (
<NavigationContainer>
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName;

        if (route.name === 'Home') {
          iconName = focused
            ? 'ios-information-circle'
            : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
        } else if (route.name === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
      },
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
  </Tab.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

);

### }

My code:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, NavigationContainer, } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs";
import {TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements'
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import HomeScreenD from './src/screens/HomeScreenD';
import IngresarAD from "./src/screens/IngresarAD";
import IngresarAutoP2 from './src/screens/IngresarAutoP2';
import SearchScreen from './src/screens/SearchScreen';
import Camera1 from './src/screens/Camara';
import Filtro from "./src/screens/Filtro";
import VehiculoScreen from './src/screens/VehiculoScreen';
import TrabajosScreen from './src/screens/TrabajosScreen';
import Camera360 from "./src/screens/Camera360Screen";
import CameraInterior from "./src/screens/CameraInteriorScreen";
import CameraTest from "./src/screens/CameraScreen";
import CameraTrabajo from "./src/screens/CameraTrabajo";
import CameraCarProfile from "./src/screens/CameraCarProfile";
import Multimedia from "./src/screens/Multimedia";
import Galeria360 from "./src/screens/Galeria360";
import GaleriaAINT from "./src/screens/GaleriaAINT";
import GaleriaDaños from "./src/screens/GaleriaDaños";
import GaleriaReparacion from "./src/screens/GaleriaReparacion";
import ListVehiculo from "./src/components/ListVehiculo";
import VerListVehiculo from "./src/screens/VerListVehiculo";
import AppHeader from "./src/components/AppHeader";
import Presupuesto from "./src/screens/Presupuesto";
import Ajustes from "./src/screens/Ajustes";
import vehiculos from "./src/api/vehiculos";

const Switch= createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        tabNavigator:createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
            {
                ingreso:createStackNavigator(
                    {
                        Home: HomeScreenD,
                        IngresarAD: IngresarAD,
                        IngresarAutoP2: IngresarAutoP2,
                        ListarAutos: SearchScreen,
                        VehiculoShow: VehiculoScreen,
                        Trabajos: TrabajosScreen,
                        Multimedia: Multimedia,
                        Galeria360: Galeria360,
                        GaleriaAINT: GaleriaAINT,
                        GaleriaDaños: GaleriaDaños,
                        GaleriaReparacion: GaleriaReparacion,
                        ListVehiculo: ListVehiculo,
                        VerListVehiculo: VerListVehiculo,
                        Filtro: Filtro,

                    },
                    {
                        initialRouteName: 'Home',
                        defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                            headerTitle: () => <AppHeader/>,
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#163F62',
                            },
                            headerLeft: buttonBack(navigation),

                        }),
                    }
                ),

                Vehiculo:createStackNavigator(
                    {
                        Vehiculo:VehiculoScreen
                    },
                    {
                        initialRouteName: 'Vehiculo',
                        defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                            headerTitle: () => <AppHeader/>,
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#163F62',
                            },
                            headerLeft: buttonBack(navigation)
                        }),

                        },
                    ),
                Presupuesto:createStackNavigator({
                    Presupuesto:Presupuesto,
                },
                    {
                        initialRouteName: 'Vehiculo',
                        defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                            headerTitle: () => <AppHeader/>,
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#163F62',
                            },
                            headerLeft: buttonBack(navigation)
                        }),
                    },),
               Ajustes:createStackNavigator({
                   Ajustes:Ajustes,
                   },
                   {
                       initialRouteName: 'Vehiculo',
                         defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
                            headerTitle: () => <AppHeader/>,
                            headerStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: '#163F62',
                            },

                             barStyle:{
                                backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'
                             },
                             headerLeft: buttonBack(navigation)
                         }),
                   },
               ),
            },


        ),

        navigator: createStackNavigator({
            Camera360: Camera360,
            CameraTest: CameraTest,
            CameraTrabajo: CameraTrabajo,
            CameraInterior: CameraInterior,
            CameraCarProfile: CameraCarProfile,
        }),
    });
const buttonBack = navigation=>(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
        <Icon type={'Feather'} name={'chevron-left'}  color={'#E59413'}/>
    </TouchableOpacity>);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer (Switch);

function App() {
    const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);
    if (!isLoadingComplete) {
        return (
            <AppLoading
                startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
                onError={handleLoadingError}
                onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
            />
        );
    }
    else {
        return isLoadingComplete ? <AppContainer /> : <AppLoading />;

    }

    }

async function loadResourcesAsync() {
    await Promise.all([
        // fuente para el builderx
        // Font.loadAsync({
        // "roboto-regular": require("./src/assets/fonts/roboto-regular.ttf")
        // })

        // fuentes para native-base
        Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
            Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
            ...Ionicons.font,
        })
    ]);
}

function handleLoadingError(error) {
    console.warn(error);
}

function handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete) {
    setLoadingComplete(true);}
    
export default App;
```

---

every time I try to implement it in my code this happens

15:03
SyntaxError: C:\Users\nicol\Documents\GitHub\proyectox-app\node_modules@react-navigation\material-bottom-tabs\src\index.tsx: Unexpected token (14:12)

12 |  * Types
  13 |  */

> 14 | export type {
>        |             ^
>     15 |   MaterialBottomTabNavigationOptions,
>     16 |   MaterialBottomTabNavigationProp,
>     17 | } from './types';
>   ERROR
>   15:03
>   Building JavaScript bundle: error

Answer (score 0):

If you use npm

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
npm install
```

If you use yarn:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn
```

[Source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#im-getting-syntaxerror-in-react-navigationxxxxxxtsx-or-syntaxerror-xxxreact-navigationxxxxxxtsx-unexpected-token)